# How do I manage multiple divs with "position: relative"?

Tags: html, css

I have an element on my page that i want to position using "position:absolute". Therefore, I have added "position: relative" to #pagewrap. I now want to do the same thing for other elements in the #page, but when I also add "position: relative" to that, all the elements before having #pagewrap as a parent now switches to #page.

The element I am talking about is: #copyright-logo

What do I do to avoid this?

```
#pagewrap {
width: 1050px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
overflow: hidden;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
position: relative;
}

#page { 
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
overflow: hidden;
 }

#copyright-logo {
position:absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px
}
```

Comment: Can we get some HTML to go with the CSS, to get an idea of the relationship from one element to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the nearest enclosing positioned element, which may be another absolutely positioned element or alternatively a fixed or a relatively positioned element.

[CSS position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)

Answer (score 1):

Make your `#copyright-logo` the direct child of `#pagewrap` and not `#page`

```
<div id="pagewrap">
    <div id="copyright-logo"></div>
    <div id="page"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overusing relative and absolute positionning.

There is absolutely no need to relatively position #pagewrap, simply center it with margins as in:

```
#pagewrap { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

In any case, don't overuse those positions but use floats and padding and margin.